# Android Activity height too long, how to swipe to bottom?

Tags: android, device, swipe, flip

I have an Activity (single) and if I flip the device I can see only the half of the Activity. I have two EditText and a Button and I can't reach them because I can't swipe to bottom. If I flip back the device everything is ok.

Is there any method that I must call to can swipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ScrollView` as Niek said.

2.Set Fixed Orientation if you Haven't designed for the LandScape mode,(i.e Either potrait or landscape)
   You can set your fixed orientation in your Manifest file like this
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` (You can apply this to your activity as well as for the application whole)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to wrap your layout.